# Google Vertex AI Prediction API Prediction request error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I am trying to pass a `Python Dict` into `aiplatform_v1.PredictRequest` and make prediction with `aiplatform_v1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient`.

I have encountered this error: `TypeError: Argument for field google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictRequest.instances is not iterable`

I have parsed my `Python Dict` into `google.protobuf` value and wrap it as a `list`, which should be iterable, as shown in this  
[Official Python Request Sample Link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_tabular_classification_sample.py)

Below please find my code for reference:

```py
from google.protobuf.struct_pb2 import Value, Struct, ListValue
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.api_core import exceptions
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

async def model_predict(json_data):

    # Load credentials from a service account key file
    key_path = 'path-to-key-file.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        key_path,
        scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    )
   
    # Set up the endpoint configs and pass user input
    project_id = "XXXXXX"
    endpoint_id = "XXXXXXX"
    instance_dict = json_data
    location = "us-central1"
    api_endpoint = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
    
    # Format user input to pass into request
    instance = json_format.ParseDict(instance_dict, Value())
    parameters_dict = {}
    parameters= json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())

    # Set up async prediction service client 
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}

    prediction_client = aiplatform_v1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient(
        credentials=credentials, client_options=client_options
    )

    # Build Prediction request
    endpoint_path = prediction_client.endpoint_path(
        project=project_id, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id,
    )

    request = aiplatform_v1.PredictRequest(
        endpoint=endpoint_path, instances= [instance], parameters = parameters
    )

    # Call the predict method asynchronously
    try:
        response = await prediction_client.predict(request=request)
        print(response)
        predictions = response.predictions

        return predictions, None

    except exceptions.GoogleAPIError as error:
        error_message = f"Prediction request failed: {error}"
        return None, error_message
```

I have printed the type and sample of instances passed through under this code.  \

`<class 'google.protobuf.struct_pb2.Value'> struct_value { fields { key: "Ticket_Subject" value { string_value: "Battery Issue" } } fields { key: "Ticket_Status" value { string_value: "Open" } } fields { key: "Ticket_Priority" value { string_value: "High" } } .... (more fields structured as above) }`

Comment: What's your instance_dict? can you share more about the content that you send to the API?

Comment: instance_dict =   
`{'Feature1': 'Value1', 'Feature2': 'Value2', 'Feature3': 'Value3', .... , 'Feature14': 'Value14'}`
All of the values are `str` and have a total of 14 features

Comment: Can you try an instance format like this: `{
  "instances": [
    {"values": ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", .... , "Value14"]}
  ]}`

Comment: Do you mean in this format? `instances = {"instances" : [input_dict]}` 
As I have 14 feature_columns with its own 14 values, do I have to specify the feature_column or not? From your answer, seems like I only have to include the value corresponded to each column without incl the feature_col name.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Only the values are required (the model required a vector, i.e. an array)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I have to construct the instance object by myself? Or are there any library functions that can help me after I have extracted all the values from my dict?
If I do have to construct it by myself, can you point me to the structure or provide some advice? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build it yourself first and try to see if it solves your issue. If so, we could try to find a solution

Comment: I tried this and it is not working still. 

`value_list =list(instance_dict.values())
 instance_data = {"values": value_list}
`

Then passed the instance_data into the`request (instances = instance_data)`

Comment: Could you share your entire code?

Comment: I have changed the code snippet to the full function of the request construction.

Comment: Does this [code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_custom_trained_model_sample.py) satisfy your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self-Answered**

#1
`Google` has updated its protobuf package to rely on `Proto Plus for Python`
[Link to Library](https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Inside the PDF documentation which is available for download, on **P.17**
You can see that only `ListValue` are considered to be `Mutable Sequence`, which is the requirement for `instance` object in Google `Prediction Request`
You can only `append` values into a `ListValue` Object, instead of direct assignment.

#2
Regarding the use of `PredictionServiceAsyncClient` to make `PredictRequest`:
You can choose not to parse the `instance_dict` and directly append instead.

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}

prediction_client = aiplatform_v1.PredictionServiceAsyncClient(
    credentials=credentials, 
    client_options=client_options
)

# Build Prediction request
# Append the input python dictonary as instances
endpoint_path = prediction_client.endpoint_path(
    project=project_id, location=location, endpoint=endpoint_id,
)

# Direct append instance_dict as instances
request = aiplatform_v1.PredictRequest()
request.endpoint = endpoint_path
request.instances.append(instance_dict)

# Call the predict method asynchronously
try:
    response = await prediction_client.predict(request=request)
    predictions = response.predictions
    return predictions, None

except exceptions.GoogleAPIError as error:
    error_message = f"Prediction request failed: {error}"
    return None, error_message
```